# Weak convergence in $BC(\mathbb R^+;X)$

Tags: functional-analysis

I know that a sequence $u_n\in C([a,b];X)$ ($X$ is a Banach space) converges weakly to $u$ iff $\{u_n\}$ is bounded and $u_n(t)$ converges weakly to $u(t)$ for each $t\in [a,b]$. Does this hold if we replace $C([a,b];X)$ by $BC(\mathbb R^+;X)$ (the space of continuous bounded functions on $\mathbb R^+$)? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not hold.

Take $X = \mathbb{R}$ and consider the subspace $E \subset BC(\mathbb{R}^+, \mathbb{R})$ consisting of functions $u$ for which $\lim_{x \to +\infty} u(x)$ exists.  Define a linear functional $f$ on $E$ by $f(u) = \lim_{x \to +\infty} u(x)$.  Verify that $f$ is continuous.  By the Hahn-Banach theorem, $f$ extends to a continuous linear functional $g$ on $BC(\mathbb{R}^+, \mathbb{R})$.  Now let $$u(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x \le 0 \\ x, &0 \le x \le 1 \\ 1, &x \ge 1 \end{cases}$$ and set $u_n(x) = u(x-n)$.  Then the sequence $\{u_n\}$ is uniformly bounded by 1 and converges pointwise to 0.  But since $u_n \in E$, we have $g(u_n) = f(u_n) = 1$ for every $n$, so $u_n$ does not converge weakly to 0.

Comment: Thank you very much, Nate. Could you please give any characterization of weak convergence in $BC(\mathbb R^+;X)$?

Comment: @KaiChen: I don't know of any convenient characterization.  The book of Dunford and Schwartz might have something.  One approach, at least for $X=\mathbb{R}$, is to use the fact that $BC(\mathbb{R}^+, \mathbb{R})$ is isometrically isomorphic to $C(\beta \mathbb{R}^+)$ where $\beta \mathbb{R}^+$ is the Stone-Cech compactification of $\mathbb{R}^+$.  Each continuous function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}^+$ has a unique continuous extension $\tilde{f}$ on $\beta \mathbb{R}^+$, so $f_n$ converges weakly to $f$ iff $\{f_n\}$ is bounded and $\tilde{f}_n$ converges pointwise to $\tilde{f}$.

Comment: @KaiChen: But this is quite nonconstructive (the space $\beta \mathbb{R}^+$ cannot be described explicitly) and so probably not really helpful.